# angular js ipad safari session

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs

I'm trying to get my website working also with ipad safari. I mean, users login my application succesfully on desktop, but on safari ipad, the session is not retained, so the user still see the login page.

I do using `$http` request with `withCredetials:true` as parameter, but it seems it doesn't work on ipad. anyone can help me?

same code works in desktop,but not using ipad browser

as backend I am using php codeigniter

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just solved by enabling cookies in my ipad safari settings:

```
Settings / Safari / Block Cookie / Always Allow
```

hope this helps